# Switching between LWUIT Form and LCDUI Form

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lcdui

I have built a LWUIT UI class which contains the Midlet. I am basically using a theme from this midlet. But I need to jump to another LCDUI form which contains some LCDUI controls and I need to set display that LCDUI form. So is it possible to jump from LWUIT form to LCDUI form and set display the LCDUI form ? If possible how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used following code to show the both LWUIT Form and LCDUI Form. See the sample code.

```
com.sun.lwuit.Form lwuitForm;
protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
    Display.init(this);
    lwuitForm = new com.sun.lwuit.Form("LWUIT Form");
    lwuitForm.addComponent(new TextField(""));

    final MIDlet midlet = this;
    final Command abtUsCmd = new Command("Next") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            javax.microedition.lcdui.Form  frm = new javax.microedition.lcdui.Form("LCDUI Form");
            StringItem item = new StringItem("Text", "Sample text");
            frm.append(item);

            final javax.microedition.lcdui.Command cmd = new javax.microedition.lcdui.Command("Back", javax.microedition.lcdui.Command.BACK, 0);
            CommandListener cmdLis = new CommandListener() {

                public void commandAction(javax.microedition.lcdui.Command c, Displayable d) {
                    if(c == cmd) {
                        Display.init(midlet);
                        lwuitForm.show(); // Show the LWUIT form again
                    }
                }
            };

            frm.setCommandListener(cmdLis);
            frm.addCommand(cmd);

            javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(midlet).setCurrent(frm); // show the LCDUI Form
        }
    };
    lwuitForm.addCommand(abtUsCmd);
    lwuitForm.show(); // Show the LWUIT Form
}
```

Comment: is it possible to set background LWUIT theme and set lcdui form on the top of it.....???

Comment: AFAIK its not possible. you are not able use both at the same time.

Comment: can we call lwuit form on top of the lcdui form? meaning i have a lcdui app and i want to just use a component (say `HtmlComponent`) from LWUIT.. so cant i make the form and show it from the current LCDUI form?

Answer (score 1):

This looks tricky, but yeah, we can switch between both.
The trick is when u show the LWUIT form, after  it has been successfully painted on the screen, make a call to

> javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(midlet).getCurrent();

this gives you the Displayable holding all the LWUIT views, so with this, you can always switch to LCDUI, and back to LWUIT with the LCDUI's

> display.setCurrent

Let me know if this works for you.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that works excellent for me. Now I can do all type of things with the native platform implementation.